# Connect fans and display to rpi 3b+

Tags: display, pi-3b+

I have a rpi 3b+. With it I bought a 3.5 inch display and a case with dual fans. But the pins for the fans (5v and ground) are the same with the display.

How can I have them both connected to my board at the same time?

Comment: Hello. It depends, do you feel you'd be able to make your own connector to combine the two sets of wires or would you prefer some intermediate hardware between your Pi and the fans/display? Both approaches have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I don't know if I can make it work if I make my own connector. But if you have some guide for it I will certainly try it. As for the intermediate hardware, it depends on the cost of it. Recommendations for both would be very useful.

Comment: Why do you need fans on the Pi3B+?

Comment: It will be operating for long periods of time and under load. So basically,  I do not want to have any gpu throttle from the heat.